# Why am I getting wrong matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I'm trying to print the following matrix and vector,

```
A = np.array ([[2,1,4,1], [3,4,-1,-1] , [1,-4,1,5] , [2,-2,1,3]], float)
v = np.array([-4, 3, 9, 7], float)
```

But I'm getting this instead

```
A = 
[[ 1.   0.5  2.   0.5]
 [ 0.   1.  -2.8 -1. ]
 [-0.  -0.   1.  -0. ]
 [-0.  -0.  -0.   1. ]]

v = [-2.   3.6 -2.   1. ]
```

If I change from float to int I get the right matrix but then I gett error when trying to run the following code

```
for m in range(N):
    div = A[m,m]
    A[m,:] /= div
    v[m] /= div
```

```
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'true_divide' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

How can I solve tis problem?

Comment: `A[m,m]` is each element of the diagonal of A, which is all ones. Why do you want to divide the elements of A and v by 1?

Comment: It's not ones actually, the original matrix is the one I defined first, but somehow I'm getting back another one!

Comment: Sorry cannot reproduce your problem.  your code (with `N=4` which you are missing) runs fine on my computer. Are you sure this is the code you are executing?

Comment: The first part is not reproducible. I copied `A = ...` and `v = ...`  lines to terminal and then `print`ed `A` and `v`. As expected, printed objects contain the same numbers as input, but coerced to float, as expected. Your attempt with using `int` instead obviously doesn't work, because result of `int / int` cannot be `int` in general, and you try to put it into a matrix of `int`.

Comment: But why am I getting another matrix when printing A(as float)? all the numbers are somehow different that the ones I wrote!

Comment: you must make sure that the code you are executing is what you posted. In the code you posted you are missing to define N, which suggests that you actually have more code that you are not showing us. Make a new file, paste exactly the code that you have in the question, add a definition for N `N=4` and run it. You will see that it gives no error.  If in your code you get other numbers is because you are somewhere else redefining variables or changing them. We cannot help with code that you have not posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess right syntax is this?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array ([[2,1,4,1], [3,4,-1,-1] , [1,-4,1,5] , [2,-2,1,3]], dtype = float)
print(A)
```

Gives #

```
[[ 2.  1.  4.  1.]
 [ 3.  4. -1. -1.]
 [ 1. -4.  1.  5.]
 [ 2. -2.  1.  3.]]
```